# Iterating Through List of Strings, Find Keywords and Print

Tags: python, string, loops

Take two lists composed of strings:

```
strings = ['hello everyone!', 'how are you doing?', 'are you doing well?', 'are you okay?', 'good, me too.']
searching_for = ['are', 'you', 'doing']
```

My goal is to search `strings` for every item in `searching_for` and print the full string that contains those keywords. i.e., I want my output to be:

```
Output: ['how are you doing?', 'are you doing well?']
```

Notice that the output is only the 2nd and 3rd items in `strings`, that it does not contain the 4th item.

I'm not sure why this is so difficult for me, but I think it boils down to me not knowing Python well enough yet. I want to make this general enough such that I can search a very large list of strings for keywords I give it. Here's my solution so far:

```
def search(*args):
    arg_list = []
    search_for = numpy.append(arg_list, args)
    
    for i in strings:
        for j in search_for:
            if all(j in i) is True:
                print(i)
```

But this throws a `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`. I've tried a few different iterations of the above code, using Pythons built-in `filter` function and a few others, but I keep getting hung up on similar errors. I'm also unsure if this will give me a list, I think it'll spit out the result on a new line in the terminal.

Comment: `all(j in i)` is either `all(True)` or `all(False)` which is causing the problem. Instead, try `if all([j in i for j in search_for]): print(i)`

Comment: Dude, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris if you post a formal answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one so you can get the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python there is a thing called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is more efficient and easier to read than long `for`-loop constructs. To create the list you are looking for, this is an example of a list comprehension:

```
result = [s for s in strings if all(sf in s for sf in searching_for)]
# ['how are you doing?', 'are you doing well?']
```

It does how it is told, straight forward in my opinion:

- Create a list of (surrounding brackets)
- the strings `s` in variable `strings`
- if all strings `sf` of variable `searching_for` can be found in `s`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
print([i for i in strings if all([s in i for s in searching_for])])
```

Output

```
['how are you doing?', 'are you doing well?']
```

This list comprehension will check if all words in `searching_for` list are in each sentence of `strings` and if so it will print the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for st in strings:
    if set(searching_for).issubset(set(st[:-1].split())):
        print(st)
```

Answer (score 1):

`all` (or `any`) will try to iter over its input; and `True` or `False` (as a result of `j in i`) is not an iterable. This is what is causing the `TypeError`:

```
all(True)
# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Instead, make your inner loop simpler:

```
def search(*args):
    arg_list = []
    search_for = numpy.append(arg_list, args)
    
    for i in strings:
        if all(j in i for j in search_for):
            print(i)
```

Or even simpler:

```
def search(args):
    for i in strings:
        if all(j in i for j in args):
            print(i)
```

Output:

```
search(searching_for)
# how are you doing?
# are you doing well?
```

Note that you *don't* need `all(...) is True` since `all` would already have returned either `True` or `False`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here you go :

```
strings = ['hello everyone!', 'how are you doing?', 'are you doing well?', 'are you okay?', 'good, me too.']
keywords = ['are', 'you', 'doing']

for s in strings:
    for word in s.split():
        if word in keywords:
            print(s) 
            break
```

Comment: Don't down vote it. I've figured out my answer doesn't exactly match the question as I print a sentence if any of the keyword is in it (instead of EVERY keywords). However, editing my answer won't bring anything new nor better than what as already been answered, so I'll just leave my answer here for whom wants it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner using list comprehension and `any()`:

```
strings = ['hello everyone!', 'how are you doing?', 'are you doing well?', 'are you okay?', 'good, me too.']
searching_for = ['are', 'you', 'doing']

print('Output:', [item for item in strings if any([word in item for word in searching_for])])
#Output: ['how are you doing?', 'are you doing well?', 'are you okay?']
```